# How to create a deb package containing multiple projects?

Tags: debian, package-management, deb

I would like to know the recommended path for creating a *.deb package (a C++ program), that depends on other C++ programs created by myself to be already installed on the system.

Is creating a package with the 2 projects a good idea? (How to do it?) or is a better idea to create different *.deb packages for every project?

Comment: It's better to create 2 deb packages and have A depend on B.

Comment: There is no reason you can't have multiple related binaries in a single package, especially when installing one without the other won't make any sense. -|-

Although from a maintenance perspective you might prefer to create separate packages which you can independently update and upgrade and then you use [dependancy declarations](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-dependencies) syntax in your control files.

Comment: The question is rather vague, but it general, one should not create a binary Debian package which contains multiple unrelated software.